# ¿Cómo validar si un objeto referenciado (@ManyToOne) anidado existe con OpenXava/JPA?

Tags: java, validación, jpa, openxava

En una aplicación OpenXava tengo una clase llamada Parcel que referencia a una clase TaxAccount:

```
@Entity 
public Parcel {

    @ManyToOne
    TaxAccount taxAccout;

}
```

También, tengo una clase llamada Assessment que referencia a Parcel:

```
@Entity
public class Assessment {

    @ManyToOne
    Parcel parcel;

}
```

Al grabar Assessment me gustaría chequear/validar si la Parcel referenciada tiene una TaxAccount asociada. Si la Parcel referenciada tiene una TaxAccount asociada la acción para grabar Assessment debería tener éxito, en caso contrario la acción de grabar fallaría.

¿Cómo consigo esto con OpenXava?

Answer (score 0):

La forma más fácil de incluir la validación es en la propia entidad, de esta manera:

```
public class Assessment {

    @AssertTrue(message="parcel_must_have_tax_account")
    private boolean parcelHasTaxAccount() {
        return parcel != null && parcel.getTaxAccount() != null;
    }

}
```

Fíjate como @AssertTrue no es una anotación OpenXava sino una anotación de Bean Validation, por lo que esta anotación funcionará con OpenXava pero también cuando uses tus entidades JPA fuera de OpenXava.

Para más alternativas de validación en OpenXava mira:

https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/validation_es.html